# Aircrack-ng: Why deauth works

Tags: aircrack-ng, wep, wpa2-psk

When using aircrack to attack WPA, deauth packets are used to force a host to deauthenticate. But the machine sending these deauth packets is not even connected to the network. How possible is it that the AP accepts packets from a machine not connected to it? In other-wards, why would an AP or end host accepts de-authentication requests from arbitrary senders who are not even connected to the network?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> AP accepts packets from a machine not connected to it
>   from arbitrary senders

Normally, deauthentication [and other management] frames **don't have to be encrypted** (i.e. require an existing authenticated 'connection' between the AP and the client). Therefore, they can be spoofed.

The way to protect against this kind of attack is to use **Management Frame Protection** (check out http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/wlan-security/82196-mfp.html#climfp):

> Specifically, **client MFP encrypts management frames** sent between access points and CCXv5 clients so that both access points and clients can take preventive action and drop **spoofed** class 3 management frames (that is, management frames passed between an access point and a client that is authenticated and associated). Client MFP leverages the security mechanisms defined by IEEE 802.11i to protect these types of class 3 unicast management frames: disassociation, **deauthentication**, and QoS (WMM) action.

**What are the legitimate uses for deauth frame?**

In addition to just that, termination of the secure communication (e.g. 'Forget this network'), there are a few possible reasons specified by 802.11, like these (reason/description):

- 2 - Previous authentication no longer valid
- 3 - Station is leaving (or has left) IBSS or ESS
- 4 - Disassociated due to inactivity

(you can read more at, for example, https://supportforums.cisco.com/document/141136/80211-association-status-80211-deauth-reason-codes or  )

**Why is it that Access Points do not implement these Management Frame Protection mechanisms?**

It is available in many APs, but usually "Optional" by default, to prevent client connectivity issues. You can read more in this answer: [802.11w protected management frames - Wi-Fi](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83356/802-11w-protected-management-frames-wi-fi)

Personally, I think that it is not such a big deal, because (a) strong PSKs make bruteforcing long and non-so-effective, (b) you can just wait for a legitimate client to leave and come back to catch the handshake. I.e. it makes it harder to get in, but doesn't prevent the possibility.

Comment: Why is it that Access Points do not implement these Management Frame Protection mechanisms ? It appears all Wi-Fi networks today are vulnerable to spoofing of deauth packets. Why are these mechanisms not used?

Comment: Also, can you please clarify on the purpose of deauth packets in practice? I know how they help to aid  attacks, but I am not sure of their legitimate purpose when a network operates normally

Comment: @Minaj added some info the the answer

Comment: Thanks. One more question: when attacking WPA, why is it that a single deauthenticate message is normally not enough to cause deauthentication? One usually has to send multiple messages to achieve deauthentication. Not sure why this is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: @Minaj I think it's because not all packets are actually received - either due to distance, signal strength, or something else; aircrack even shows you number of ACKs from AP and the client for the deauth packets