# With WiFi now having protected management frames, is it still worth attempting an evil twin attack?

Tags: wpa2, aircrack-ng, wpa2-psk, evil-twin, deauth-attack

I was trying to aireplay'ng my home WiFi but I understood that with the new generation of APs, there is a system of protected management frames. So I'm asking, is it still worth it to perform an evil twin attack? I think not, because without deauthenticating a station, the client will never go to search for a new connection.

So, what is your opinion? And is there any new way to perform an attack on WPA2?

Comment: Potential duplicate: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83356/802-11w-protected-management-frames-wi-fi

Comment: From the top answer of the question that schroeder posted, I think this may indeed answer your question: "802.11w is NOT there to defend against someone determined who [can do X, or] can just jam every 2.4Ghz frame on those channels in that area." If the target is in signal reach, as they would be for an evil twin attack, you can probably make them look for a new access point.

Comment: 802.11w is _far_ from common in home networks.

Answer (score 1):

Evil twin attacks are still possible. Deauth is only one of the things that can be used in evil twin attacks, are not the most crucial. Maybe the client's WiFi is turned off, then when it is turned on, it sees the evil twin. It may try to authenticate with, and associate with, the evil twin. Even though there has been no deauth attack done on the client.